# How to run 2 functions simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I know this question had been answered a thousand times, but i still can't get the functions to work at the same time. Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    a();
    a();
}

static void a()
{
    string sampleString = "a";
    Console.WriteLine(sampleString);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop -1);
        sampleString = " " + sampleString;
        Console.WriteLine(sampleString);
    }
}
```

The function just writes the letter 'a' and after 0.1 seconds adds a space behind it, not complicated. After the function ends, it does the same thing again. I want both of the functions to work at the same time, the first function in the first line and the second in the second line. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asynchronous programming is a really broad topic. I'd recommend reading [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If the question has been answered a thousand of times, why you did not implemented any of the solutions instead of ask it again?

Comment: He is asking for a way to come back to previously outputted line and add space to it.

Comment: Simultaneously means nothing. Even using asynchronous programming (that´s what you´re after) your computer is only able to process one task at a time. However you can switch between parallell tasks quite fast making you feel it happens simultaneously.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Just a pedantic correction *Even using asynchronous programming (that´s what you´re after) your computer is only able to process one task at a time*, that's not true on multi-core processors...

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Although multiple-core CPUs do run simultaneously.

Comment: Something like `Parallel.Invoke(() => a(); () => a());`? `Parallel.For(0, 10, i => whatever);`?

Comment: Even this would work: `Action action = a; action.BeginInvoke(null, null); action.BeginInvoke(null, null);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Parallel` class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parallel.Invoke(a,a);
}
```

You functions will be run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create two threads, start them and wait for them to finish. For your specific question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = new Thread(a); t1.Start();
    var t2 = new Thread(a); t2.Start();
    t1.Join(); t2.Join();
}
```

But of course, this does not solve your initial problem, writing into different lines of the console, as the `a` function does not know, which line to write on. You could solve this, by adding a parameter with the line number.

Furthermore, you'll have to protect your console output by a lock, because it's a single target where multiple sources write data into, which may lead to inconsistencies if not synchronized correctly. So I really suggest, that you read some tutorials on multi-threading.

Comment: @Transcendental care to explain?

Comment: Define "easiest".  Did you see Roma's answer?

Comment: @roryap Point taken.